# Laravel 5.4 - Site-wide authentication checking

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm looking to find the best way to implement site-wide authentication checking in Laravel 5.4

I'm building a website that has a growing number of pages that check for rows in a database assigned to a user. If someone visits a page on the site that carries out this function, and they are not logged in, Laravel will give

"Trying to get property of non-object"

and display its error page.

I need to remove **all** Laravel error pages from my project, to clean it up, and I'm starting with these errors:

**Current solution:**

My current solution is that wherever a route makes these checks in a controller, I wrap it in

```
if (Auth::check()) {
```

I'm wondering if there is a better solution other than wrapping all such code in this?

**Edit**
I need to go and learn how middleware works.

Comment: Can you not just use the `auth` middleware? Then the page is inaccessible if a user isn't logged in.

Comment: Use `auth` middleware in routes which is suppose to be accessed by an authenticated user.

Comment: @fubar I pretty much have no idea what middleware is and have been meaning to go and learn it... guess I better go and do that right away! Thanks for the input